# Printing table to the console with selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to print the data of table from this site

http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/il/homepage

try to make a book then you will see the availability
of the flights this is my code :

[image: From this html code I want to print the branded-fares-flights table]

```
String from_to = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.branded-fares-flights")).getText();
        System.out.println(from_to);
```

Its not working. It tells me that there is no such element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: When you enter this site , you make a book 
for example from paris to berlin , then you choose a denaturing  date and then return date , and click search , so you see two tables I want to bring them and print in the console thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, it seems you have identified only table element using cssSelector(driver.findElement) and then trying to print all its content, it won't work. You have go down the level from table to tr/td then print its text. Also since in your case multiple element will be returned so you to have use **driver.findElements** instead of driver.findElement. Try with the below code, you might need to modify little bit as per your requirement.

```
// Get all the table row elements from the table 
List<WebElement> allRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='branded-fares-flights']//tr")); 

// And iterate over them and get all the cells 
for (WebElement row : allRows) { 
    List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 

    // Print the contents of each cell
    for (WebElement cell : cells) {         

    System.out.println(cell.getText());
    //Or try below code 
    //System.out.println(cell.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
}
```

Comment: you tried this and it worked  ? 

WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.branded-fares-flights"));

Comment: To try, I have to first write code for booking ticket and then only I can check whether I am able to get content of table. However the above code should work in your case. I have edited the above code, used x-path for identifying collection of rows, give it a try once.